# Is it possible to track how many event listener does the specific smart contract have?

Tags: web3js, ethers.js, events, event-handling

I'm wondering if the above question is possible in ethers or web3? If yes, is it possible to get their IP as well? Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Umh, no.

Each event listener uses a node to read its data. The closest thing you can do is track nodes with something like https://ethernodes.org/ , but you won't have much knowledge about what the nodes are used for. In theory you might be able to (somewhat) track which node broadcasts which transaction, if you have direct access to many nodes, but in reality you can't do even that. And for read-only operations (such as event listening) there is no way to know.